# How to use std::set_terminate with SetUnhandledExceptionFilter?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, c++17

Is there any way I can get the `.what()` of an uncaught C++ exception while also having a windows unhandled exception filter installed?

To demonstrate, the following program...

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

static LONG WINAPI WindowsExceptionHandler(LPEXCEPTION_POINTERS ep) {
    std::cerr << "FOO" << std::endl;
    return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
}

void TerminateHandler() {
    std::exception_ptr exception_ptr = std::current_exception();
    try {
        if (exception_ptr) std::rethrow_exception(exception_ptr);
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(WindowsExceptionHandler);
    std::set_terminate(TerminateHandler);
    throw std::runtime_error("BAR");
}
```

outputs:

```
FOO
```

I want it to output either `BAR` or `FOOBAR`

Commenting out the `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` makes it work (but that's unacceptable as it won't catch the other windows exception types).

Clearly `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` somehow overrides `std::set_terminate` in some way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

all c++ exceptions internal use [throw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/try-throw-and-catch-statements-cpp?view=vs-2019) keyword. internal it use [`_CxxThrowException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/cxxthrowexception?view=vs-2019) and this api call [`RaiseException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-raiseexception) function with [`0xE06D7363`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100730-00/?p=13273) in place *dwExceptionCode*. so you need call previous exception filter returned by [`SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-setunhandledexceptionfilter) for C++ exceptions if want handle it with `TerminateHandler`.

```
g_prevlpTopLevelExceptionFilter = SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(WindowsExceptionHandler);
```

and

```
if (ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == 0xE06D7363) {
    return g_prevlpTopLevelExceptionFilter(ep);
}
```

---

```
LPTOP_LEVEL_EXCEPTION_FILTER g_prevlpTopLevelExceptionFilter;

LONG WINAPI WindowsExceptionHandler(LPEXCEPTION_POINTERS ep) {

    PEXCEPTION_RECORD ExceptionRecord = ep->ExceptionRecord;

    printf("%s: %x at %p", __FUNCTION__, 
        ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode, ExceptionRecord->ExceptionAddress);

    if (ULONG NumberParameters = ExceptionRecord->NumberParameters)
    {
        printf(" { ");
        PULONG_PTR ExceptionInformation = ExceptionRecord->ExceptionInformation;
        do 
        {
            printf(" %p", (void*)*ExceptionInformation++);
        } while (--NumberParameters);
        printf(" } ");
    }

    printf("\n");

    if (ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == 0xE06D7363) {
        return g_prevlpTopLevelExceptionFilter(ep);
    }

    return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
}

void TerminateHandler() {
    MessageBoxW(0, 0, __FUNCTIONW__, MB_ICONWARNING);
    exit(-1);
}

void main() {
    g_prevlpTopLevelExceptionFilter = 
        SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(WindowsExceptionHandler);
    set_terminate(TerminateHandler);
    throw "888";
}
```

Comment: Useless trivia: The low 3 bytes of the exception code (`0xE06D7363`) translate to the ASCII characters `msc`. The `E0` is probably short for *"exception"*, but couldn't be translated to ASCII without losing the MSB.